# Importing a dll into another dll C++

Tags: c++, dll, c-preprocessor, dllimport, dllexport

I have multiple classes in multiple dll's and each dll's may include other.

I use the following macro in order to specify the `__declspec` parameter for all the headers of my dll's :

```
#ifdef DLL_UTIL_A
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Let's say dllA is including dllB.
The thing is, when I include dllB's header file in dllA, the macro `DLLEXPORT` is redefined to import the classes from dllB's header file. When the pre-processor returns to dllA to continue it's parsing, it has an updated `DLLEXPORT` with an updated unwanted value.

Should I use different defines for each dll's (ex. replace `DLLEXPORT` by `DLLEXPORT_DLL_A`) or is there a clean way to get the `DLLEXPORT`'s old value back when returning in dllA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different macro name for DLLEXPORT for both DLLs.

Comment: Thanks, I needed that confirmation!